# Getting FramebufferIncompleteMultisample when trying to create a multisampled framebuffer

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, opentk, multisampling

I use the following code to create a texture + framebuffer (using openTK in C#):

```
    public void Create(int width, int height, SurfaceFormat format)
    {
        bool multisample = format.Multisample > 1;
        int samples = Math.Max(1, Math.Min(format.Multisample, 4));
        TextureTarget target = multisample ? TextureTarget.Texture2DMultisample : TextureTarget.Texture2D;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        textureHandle = GL.GenTexture();
        //bind texture
        
        GL.BindTexture(target, textureHandle);
        Log.Error("Bound Texture: " + GL.GetError());
        GL.TexParameter(target, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Nearest);
        GL.TexParameter(target, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
        GL.TexParameter(target, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)format.WrapMode);
        GL.TexParameter(target, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)format.WrapMode);
        
        Log.Error("Created Texture Parameters: " + GL.GetError());
        if (format.Multisample < 2)
            GL.TexImage2D(target, 0, format.InternalFormat, Width, Height, 0, format.PixelFormat, format.SourceType, format.Pixels);
        else
            GL.TexImage2DMultisample(TextureTargetMultisample.Texture2DMultisample, samples, format.InternalFormat, Width, Height, false);
        Log.Error("Created Image: " + GL.GetError());
        //unbind texture
        GL.BindTexture(target, 0);
        //create depthbuffer
        if (format.DepthBuffer)
        {
            GL.GenRenderbuffers(1, out dbHandle);
            GL.BindRenderbuffer(RenderbufferTarget.RenderbufferExt, dbHandle);
            
            if(multisample)
                GL.RenderbufferStorageMultisample(RenderbufferTarget.RenderbufferExt, samples, RenderbufferStorage.Depth24Stencil8, Width, Height);
            else
                GL.RenderbufferStorage(RenderbufferTarget.RenderbufferExt, RenderbufferStorage.DepthComponent24, Width, Height);
        }

        //create fbo
        fboHandle = GL.GenFramebuffer();
        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, fboHandle);
        GL.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0Ext, target, textureHandle, 0);
        
        if(format.DepthBuffer)
            GL.FramebufferRenderbuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.DepthAttachmentExt, RenderbufferTarget.RenderbufferExt, dbHandle);
        Log.Debug("Framebuffer status: " + GL.CheckFramebufferStatus(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt));
        Log.Error("Created Framebuffer: " + GL.GetError());
        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0);
    }
```

And I'm getting the following errors:

> [ERROR]: Created Texture Parameters: InvalidEnum
>
> [LOG]: Framebuffer status: FramebufferIncompleteMultisample

when I try to create a surface with multisampling (2)

Any Ideas what's going wrong ? The code works find with ms < 2.

Answer (score 7):

The `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error is triggered because `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` is not valid as the first argument of the `TexParameter()` calls.

Multisample textures can only be accessed in shaders with the `texelFetch()` function. They do not support mipmaps, linear sampling, or any of the other sampling attributes. Therefore, `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` is not a valid target for `glTexParameteri()`.

On the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE` error, this is most likely caused by the last argument to this call:

```
GL.TexImage2DMultisample(TextureTargetMultisample.Texture2DMultisample, samples,
                         format.InternalFormat, Width, Height, false);
```

The last argument is *fixedsamplelocations*, so the call disables fixed sample locations.

The framebuffer completeness section of the OpenGL specs includes this error condition:

> The value of TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS is the same for all attached textures; and, if the attached images are a mix of renderbuffers and textures, the value of TEXTURE_FIXED_SAMPLE_LOCATIONS must be TRUE for all attached textures.
>   {FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE}

This is exactly the condition you have. The attachments of your FBO are a mix of textures and renderbuffers. To avoid this error, the texture must use fixed sample locations. This is done by changing the last argument in the call above to true:

```
GL.TexImage2DMultisample(TextureTargetMultisample.Texture2DMultisample, samples,
                         format.InternalFormat, Width, Height, true);
```

Comment: I still get FramebufferIncompleteMultisample when I remove the tex params though ;(

Comment: When I use true instead of false for fixedSampleLocations I still get the same error :(

Comment: I've been trying to find an answer regarding fixed_sample_locations for longer than I care to admit.  Thank you.